# Wordpress dynamic navigation function for highlighting single post tabs

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to write a function which I can re-use in my WordPress themes that will allow me to build robust dynamic navigation menus. Here is what I have so far:

```
function tab_maker($page_name, $href, $tabname) {

    //opens <li> tag to allow active class to be inserted if tab is on proper page
    echo "<li";
    //checks that we are on current page and highlights tab as active if so
    if(is_page($page_name)){
        echo " class='current_page_item'>";
    }

    //closes <li> tab if not active
    else {
        echo ">";
    }
    //inserts the link as $href and the name of the tab to appear as $tabname then closes <li>
    echo  "<a href=$href>$tabname</a>";
    echo  "</li>";
}
```

This code works as expected except I cant enable it to highlight for a single blog post as the page names are dynamic.

I know about the WordPress function `is_single()` which I've used to implement this feature in previous nav menus but I can't find a way to integrate it into this function.

Answer (score 0):

I can see were your going with this, 
inside your if statement for the is_page

can you use,

```
function tab_maker($name, $href, $tabname) {

    if(is_page($name)){
            echo " class='current_page_item'>";
    }else **if(is_single($name)){
            echo " class='current_page_item'>";**
    }else{
            echo ">";
    }
    echo  "<a href=$href>$tabname</a>";
    echo  "</li>";
}
```

haven't tried this myself